# NHibernate second level cache performance issue

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller

I am developing a MVC application with NHibernate using the session per request pattern. Most of the time users just read data and therefore i am trying to make use of NHibernate's second level cache in the following manner: I've setup SysCache and have made all my persistant entities cacheable (cache usage="nonstrict-read-write") and on application start I make calls to load all commonly used entities from the database like so:

```
var all = Session.QueryOver<T>().Cacheable().List<T>()
```

For evaluation purposes I trace the execution time for the above call and for approximately 50000 results it's ~5 seconds the first time and ~2.5 seconds for any subsequent calls to the cached query.... NHibernate Profiler says the query to the database takes less than 100ms, what takes so much time then? I tried switching providers but got similar (if not worse) results with Velocity and Memcached... I read virtually all I could find regarding NHibernate and its use of the second level cache and I think, though I may not be entirely correct, that in the above statement what happens is: 50000 objects are constructed and their data is stored in the entity and query caches and the session timestamp saved in the timestamp cache. How could that take 5 seconds on an i5 machine? Even if that is normal how just reading the cached data take 2.5 seconds in the subsequent calls with no changes inbetween? Since I am relatively new to NHibernate, can any of you help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated...I've been banging my head against the wall for a week now...

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't put 50000 entities in your cache, that negates the point of having a database, especially if your data comes from a SELECT * FROM TABLE. If it comes from a REALLY expensive query, then caching cost is less than query cost, and it should be put in the cache.

Use queries to get specific data. Then, look for the pages that make most queries, and optimize them, using a cache if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. While I have recently come to realize that what you say is indeed the way to use NH (and unspecific queries like mine above even trigger an alert in NH profiler), should only expensive queries be cached, provided that data in the DB is seldom changed? Also, I am working towards designing the data access layer in a way that only specific queries or queries with a bound result set will be issued, but nonetheless, I am interested in what may be the cause for the huge cost of the statement I quoted, in order to discover any caching issues I might have...

Comment: Use caching for frequently called queries, and set expiration date according to change frequency.

Comment: just to expand on @mathieu's very correct answer- I believe that your assumption is correct: the long execution time stems from the fact that nHib cache actually saves just the properties of the cached objects and their values, and not whole objects.  the objects themselves are constructed on every read. so these are your 2.5 secs.