# When is it recommended to use second level cache in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, performance, nhibernate

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068932/nhibernate-second-level-cache-performance-issue) question-answer explaining that usage of second level cache on 50,000 rows isn't efficient.
So on which amount of data NHibernate second cache is helpful and when it's not and even ruins  performance?

For example: if I have 3,500 Employees (Which I still don't...) will it be a good thing to use the second level cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mainly use it for 'static' data. Example is a website that does business in selling flight tickets via a shopping site. The shopping bag, orders and orderlines are volatile data. Those are not cached.

But the location data like airports, and the airline data and all the connected names in different languages are 'static'. Those can be cached for long and will than not cause roundtrips to the database every time your app needs those.

So, make a distinguishment between your static and volatile data.

What exactly to cache, what not and how long; Always depends on the usage of your application of course. Use different cache regions with different expire times when needed.

Comment: How can I set the cache expiration with fluent NH?

Comment: Same as with xml mappings; you define cache regions with their experation in the app.config or web config and use the cache region in your fluent mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer to that kind of question is not trivial.

Caches will almost always improve your performance when data is read more than it's written, but the only way to see if it helps in your particular case is profiling.

Also, it's never an all-or-nothing proposition. You will likely benefit from caching *some* entities and *some* queries. With different lifetimes, usages, etc.